# MonoGame 3.5 Pipeline Tool and using XML serialization

Tags: pipeline, monogame

I'm new at MonoGame and I have been googling tutorial videos on youtube.
However, it seems that everybody uses the old XNA content manager and XML serialization

What I'm wondering is how would I follow their methods in the new MonoGame 3.5 with the new MonoGame pipeline

I've heard you can use class libraries but I can't seem to get them working and there are no video tutorials explaining what these old methods actually did and why people used them vs the the new ones

I've heard you can't serialize and deserialize XML assets since the new MonoGame  doesn't support them which is confusing for me and also needs explaining.

I'm not very good at reading and understanding what people mean
that's why I usually use video tutorials.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific with what you're trying to do? Perhaps link to one of the video tutorials and explain the goal of serializing the XML data? Do you already have some XML content you're trying to deserialize? What does it look like, what is it used for?

Comment: this is what I'm trying to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iemvj6W-CYw also I have a backup project but its skrewed up becouse of visual studio online. I am trying to serialize the tiles.